# How to prevent crashing when running multi-threaded calculations then plotting the emitted results

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, pyqt, pyside2

I am writing a PySide2 app that plots the results to a certain calculation and trying to multithread the calculation to avoid locking up the GUI. I am trying to use QThreadPool to, upon interacting with options relating to the plot, run the calculation in a separate thread that returns the results via a signal to a callback method, which plots the results using matplotlib.

The problem is that when I change the selection of options in too quick (but not unreasonably quick) succession, the app crashes. This does not occur if the threading is removed.

I know a lot of problems are caused by having the plotting happen in the worker thread rather than the main thread so I believe I have made sure that the plotting only happens in the main thread.

I guess part of the problem is that I might be misunderstanding what is running where when using signals and slots. I have tried finding what thread is being used at different points in the code but can only use QThread.currentThread(),  which returns the address and doesn't really help as QThread.currentThreadId() leads to this error: AttributeError: type object 'PySide2.QtCore.QThread' has no attribute 'currentThreadId'.

I have tried to isolate the behaviour by writing a minimal version of the app that crashes similarly, the majority of which I have put below. I have excluded the calculation as I am not sure if I can share it and I have replaced the plot options with a QListWidget with a few options. It requires more interaction to crash than the proper app that in some cases crashes after selecting just a few options in the space of a second or two but hopefully illustrates the point.

```
class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.main_window = QMainWindow()
        self.main_window.setCentralWidget(QWidget())
        self.main_window.centralWidget().setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
        self.setup_main_window()

    def setup_main_window(self):
        print(f'setup_main_window thread address: {QThread.currentThreadId()}')
        self.load_list()
        self.plot_figure = PlotFigure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.plot_figure)
        self.plot_figure.plot(update=False)
        self.main_window.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(self.canvas)

    def load_list(self):
        self.order_list = QListWidget(self.main_window)
        self.list_items = [
            QListWidgetItem('1', self.order_list),
            QListWidgetItem('2', self.order_list),
            QListWidgetItem('3', self.order_list),
            QListWidgetItem('4', self.order_list),
        ]
        self.order_list.itemClicked.connect(self.order_list_item_changed)
        self.main_window.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(self.order_list)

    def order_list_item_changed(self):
        print(f'order_list_item_changed thread address: {QThread.currentThreadId()}')
        self.plot_figure.plot()

    def show(self):
        if self.main_window is not None:
            self.main_window.show()

class PlotFigure(Figure):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def plot(self):
        print(f'plot thread address: {QThread.currentThreadId()}')
        print(f'update: {update}')
        print(f'connecting signals')
        worker = Worker(self.calc)
        #worker.signals.close.connect(self.set_end_calc)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.plot_result)
        print(f'threads: {QThreadPool.globalInstance().activeThreadCount()}')
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(worker)

    def plot_result(self, m, xs, ys):
        print(f'plot_result thread address: {QThread.currentThreadId()}')
        print('plotting')
        fig = self.canvas.figure
        fig.clear()
        self.axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.image = self.axis.imshow(m,
                origin='lower', 
                aspect='auto',
                cmap=matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('inferno'), 
                interpolation='bilinear',
                extent=(xs[0], xs[-1], ys[0], ys[-1])
        )
        self.canvas.draw()
```

```
class WorkerSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    close = QtCore.Signal(bool)
    start = QtCore.Signal(bool)
    finished = QtCore.Signal(list, list, list)

class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, worker_method):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        self.worker_method = worker_method

    def run(self):
        self.signals.close.emit(True)
        print('close signal sent')
        m, xs, ys = self.worker_method()
        print('calc done')
        self.signals.finished.emit(m, xs, ys)
```

I should be able to select new options (click around the list widget), start a new thread from the threadpool, which runs the calculation and sends back the results to be plotted. When too many options are selected in a short time, the app crashes. This doesn't happen when everything happens in the main thread.

Can anyone tell me why the app might be crashing and offer solutions to fix the crash?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I tried to cut down the problem to only what I thought was relevant but I understand that there's still quite a bit. Is this not minimal enough or not complete or verifiable enough?

Comment: The minimum by itself is the easiest to achieve since it only involves erasing code, but here we do not require it to be only minimal, but it is complete, that is, you do not have to patch code to reproduce your problem, and if it complies with the above It means that it is reproducible, and the objective is that we have a small code that, when executed without problems,

Comment: [cont] we could analyze the problem itself. If your code needs to patch code then that involves time that we do not want to invest, another problem of patch code is that maybe in the part of the code you do not show this problem so we could never solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The crashing behaviour you're describing points to multiple threads attempting to operate on the same data/variables simultaneously. As you don't limit the number of additional threads that can be spun up, this is quite likely to happen if the user triggers multiple workers in quick succession.

There are a few ways to deal with this, which you pick depends on your requirements.

#### Copy data

If the crash is occurring because two threads are accessing the same memory, a simple solution is to take a copy of the data. Note that for lists, dicts, etc. you will need to `deepcopy` the data to ensure the nested values are also copied. For large data this can cause some overhead.

You haven't included your `calc` method in your example so I can't suggest how to do this in your case, but generally.

```
from copy import copy
data = 'a simple string'
data_c = copy(data)
```

Or, deepcopy

```
from copy import deepcopy
data = {'a':'dict', 'of':'items'}
data_c = deepcopy(data)
```

#### Worker locks

If you have a specific worker that should only run one at a time, you can implement a primitive lock. The below assumes you want the *latest* worker to run always, and will discard any earlier workers when a new task arrives.

```
self._worker_lock = False
self._worker_waiting = False
```

Each workers `.finished` signal should be connected to a method that performs.

```
def worker_finised(self):
    self._worker_lock = False
    if self._worker_waiting: 
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(self._worker_waiting)
        self._worker_waiting = False
```

This will auto-start the next worker when the current one finishes. If you want all workers that occur to run you can use a `list` queue instead.

Finally, when starting the worker.

```
def plot()
    worker = Worker(self.calc)
    worker.signals.finished.connect(self.plot_result)

    if self._worker_lock:
        self._worker_waiting = worker
    else:
        self._worker_lock
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(worker)
```

#### Limit threads to 1

This is the dumb approach, and it also prevents you from making use of threads for other calculations and renders the threadpool useless.

```
threadpool = QThreadPool()
threadpool. setMaxThreadCount(1)
```

Even then this might not be enough if the draw and calc methods can still end up executing at the same time, you'll still get crashes. But if your threads are conflicting only with each other it can be sufficient.